# Why Server Sent Event Constantly Sent request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, server-sent-events

You see the issue at last image. Even after all message display in UI and there is no message at source. It continuously polling data.

**JS Code**

```
function contentLoaded() {
    var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:50665/Home/message');
    var ul = document.getElementById("messages");
    source.onmessage = function (e) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var returnedItem = JSON.parse(e.data)
    li.textContent = returnedItem.message + ' ' + returnedItem.item;
    ul.appendChild(li);
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", contentLoaded, false);
```

**MVC Code**

```
public ActionResult Message()
        {
            var result = string.Empty;
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (_data.TryTake(out result, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)))
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var serializedObject = ser.Serialize(new { item = result, message = "hello" });
                sb.AppendFormat("data: {0}\n\n", serializedObject);
            }
            return Content(sb.ToString(), "text/event-stream");
        }
```

**Issue**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server-Sent Events via MVC, get simultaneously result and error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043254/server-sent-events-via-mvc-get-simultaneously-result-and-error)

Comment: I've marked this as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/22043254/841830 because though the question is different, I believe the answer there is also the answer here.  (I.e. your server-side script keeps closing the connection, so the browser waits a few seconds then reconnect; the server-side should enter a permanent loop, and never return, when using SSE).

Comment: If it is in permanent loop then don't you think it become similar to polling ? it means one method at server side has to be in infinite loop or something.

Comment: Different to polling, but yes to your second point. Both the pro and the con of SSE (and the previous comet techniques, and web sockets) is that you have a socket and server-side process dedicated to each client. You've traded lower latency for higher resource usage.
If resources are more important than latency, then use ajax polling, e.g. a javascript timer to send a polling request every 15 seconds or every 60 seconds: basically, choose the longest polling gap your users can tolerate.